# ClassCastException - java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.codename1.ui.Image

Tags: codenameone

I am consuming a JSON string that contains an image object among other objects. From this I create a PropertyBusinessObject which has a the following

```
public final Property<EncodedImage, Profile> profilePic = new Property<>("profilePic", EncodedImage.class);
```

I have created a method in the PropertyBusinessObject

```
public EncodedImage getProfilePic() {
    return profilePic.get();
}
```

I populate my data into the Property business object as follows:

```
profile.getPropertyIndex().populateFromMap((Map) profileObject);
```

When I try to display the image on the form using the following code,

```
ScaleImageLabel profilePic = new ScaleImageLabel(profile.getProfilePic()) {
        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            Dimension dimension = super.calcPreferredSize(); 
            dimension.setHeight(Math.min(dimension.getHeight(), Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(40)));
            return dimension;
        }
    };
    profilePic.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
    container.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, profilePic);
```

I get a ClassCastException

> Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.codename1.ui.Image

Can anyone help me resolve, or suggest another way of consuming the JSON string?

Comment: What format is the image? base64?

Comment: The image is Base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`populateFromMap` doesn't currently support Base64 images, I'll add that as an option as that use case makes sense. Should be there with the Friday update.

Comment: Thanks Shai. Much appreciated. In the meantime, can you please give some direction on how else I can achieve the same?

Comment: You can go over the map and replace the string data with an image using Base64 decode. Either way it will be there in 2 days so a workaround might not be needed